# dissecting a generic type

Tags: c#

Suppose `t` is variable of type `System.Type` with the value

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]
```

Is there a method I can call on `t` such that it will return:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
```

Otherwise, I'm thinking of calling `.ToString()` and using a regex (yuck)

Comment: When I read the question, I assumed you wanted the `Type` instance that you get for `typeof(Dictionary<,>)`. However, the other answers seem to assume that you want the **string** `"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary"` (which I would find weird because it refers to a non-existent type). Perhaps you should clarify the question. But then again, the answers already adequately answer both possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [Timwi's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673020/dissecting-a-generic-type-c/4673047#4673047) and [Vilx-'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673020/dissecting-a-generic-type-c/4673064#4673064) answers, you might write a method to do something like this:

```
// Omitted null checking, type validation, etc. for brevity
static string GetNonGenericTypeName(Type genericType)
{
    Type baseType = genericType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

    // This is PROBABLY fine since the ` character is not allowed in C# for one of
    // your own types.
    int stopIndex = baseType.FullName.IndexOf('`');

    return baseType.FullName.Substring(0, stopIndex);
}
```

**Addendum**: The above method (even aside from its lack of robustness from not validating input) suffers from a limitation that may or may not be significant, depending on the scope in which it would hypothetically be used: it assumes that the backtick character (`) would *only* occur in a class name if it were put there by the C# compiler; in other words, it assumes that any class it inspects is either from the BCL (which I don't *believe* includes any types with backticks in their names, aside from the generic ones of course) or written in C#, the "normal" way (i.e., not using some dynamic type definition library, for example).

It may well work for VB.NET and other .NET languages as well, but I'm less familiar with the naming rules of those languages so I can't currently say for sure.

If you were only using this method in your own internal library then obviously you would have control over whether or not the potential presence of backticks in a non-generic class name were realistic or even possible. If it were in a public library then it would be susceptible to returning inaccurate results for what I'll call more "exotic" but perfectly legal CLR types.

Comment: the backtick character is perfectly legal in CLR class names. How else could the C# compiler generate them in generic types?

Comment: @Timwi: You're right, I should have worded that comment differently and included a big caveat in the code... I will update.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`. But you can get `` System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 `` (i.e. the equivalent of `typeof(Dictionary<,>)`) by calling

```
t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

Comment: If he amends his question so his second snippet reads "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
<>" then your answer is absolutely right.

Comment: Yes, your answer is really what I needed (i.e. I just need a string I can reliably compare to), but I had to mark the answer that technically did answer my question exactly as written (I upvoted you though :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method which will yield the "generic" type. That will still have the `` `2 `` appended. That's because that **is** the real type name to which it is compiled (the 2 is the count of generic parameters). From there I think you have little choice but to use string manipulation.